# How to process filenames separated by new line?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm using 2 files
1° Is findjava.py, this file outputs all java file names in a directory, separated by \n
2° countfile receives 1 single filename and counts its lines

I'm already receiving an string with the filenames in count file ( javafile1\njavafile2\njavafile3\n)

How could I run a loop to go trough all those file names one by one?
I'd need to read that string till it finds a \n, then use that part as a variable to run my script to count the lines, and then keep reading the next file name.

Comment: If you find my answer sufficient could you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Split on `\n`

So something like

```
files = "javafile1\njavafile2\njavafile3\n"

list_of_files = files.split("\n")
for file in list_of_files:
    with open(file) as fh:
        lines = fh.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't leave any example data, unless it's somehow complicated by other factors it seems you can split() the data without further ado:

```
files = "javafile1\njavafile2\njavafile3\n"

for name in files.split():
  print "counting lines in file " + name
  countfile(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use a for loop to access a file one line at a time:

```
with open("file_list") as stream:
    for filename in stream:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                lines += 1
        print f, lines
```

Comment: Instead of incrementing lines you could make use of enumerate() and use k,v instead.